# Acquire a lock on two mutexes and avoid deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

The following code contains a potential deadlock, but seems to be necessary: to safely copy data to one container from another, both containers must be locked to prevent changes from occurring in another thread.

```
void foo::copy(const foo & rhs)
{
    pMutex->lock();
    rhs.pMutex->lock();
    // do copy
}
```

Foo has an STL container and "do copy" essentially consists of using std::copy. How do I lock both mutexes without introducing deadlock?

Comment: `std::lock` has a deadlock-avoidance algorithm pass it both mutexes and it will be more readable to other's than implementing your own.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Impose some kind of total order on instances of `foo` and always acquire their locks in either increasing or decreasing order, *e.g.*, `foo1->lock()` and then `foo2->lock()`.

Another approach is to use functional semantics and instead write a `foo::clone` method that creates a new instance rather than clobbering an existing one.

If your code is doing lots of locking, you may need a complex deadlock-avoidance algorithm such as the [banker's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker%27s_algorithm).

Comment: Even something as simple as the addresses of this vs rhs would work. always lock the one with the lower address first.

Comment: clone would only work well if it weren't copying, and I don't think implicit sharing will work, but I'll take a look.

Interesting approach Kyle. I can't see any flaws.

Comment: it's a nice solution to suggest to him to make a temporary copy of the data.
 `std::lock` already offers such a deadlock-avoidance algorithm however. and would be more readable

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
void foo::copy(const foo & rhs)
{
    scopedLock lock(rhs.pMutex); // release mutex in destructor
    foo tmp(rhs);
    swap(tmp); // no throw swap locked internally
}
```

This is exception safe, and pretty thread safe as well. To be 100% thread save you'll need to review all code path and than re-review again with another set of eyes, after that review it again...

Answer (score 1):

As @Mellester mentioned you can use `std::lock` for locking multiple mutexes avoiding deadlock.

```
#include <mutex>

void foo::copy(const foo& rhs)
{
    std::lock(pMutex, rhs.pMutex);

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l1(pMutex, std::adopt_lock);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l2(rhs.pMutex, std::adopt_lock);

    // do copy
}
```

But note to check that `rhs` is not a `*this` since in this case `std::lock` will lead to UB due to locking same mutex.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't do `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` first with `std::defer_lock` and then perform `std::lock(l1,l2);` ? Or is it just personal preference / style?

Comment: I don't think `std::lock` is atomic. That would still allow deadlock, right?

Comment: @cowlinator https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock `Locks the given Lockable objects lock1, lock2, ..., lockn using a deadlock avoidance algorithm to avoid deadlock`

Answer (score -1):

To avoid a deadlock its probably best, to wait until both resources can be locked:

Dont know which mutex API you are using so here is some arbitrary pseudo code, assume that `can_lock()` only checks if it can lock a mutex, and that `try_lock()` returns true if it did lock, and false, if the mutex is already locked by somebody else.

```
void foo::copy(const foo & rhs)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        if(! pMutex->cany_lock() || ! rhs.pMutex->cany_lock())
        {
            // Depending on your environment call or dont call sleep()
            continue;
        }
        if(! pMutex->try_lock())
            continue;
        if(! rhs.pMutex->try_lock())
        {
            pMutex->try_lock()
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    // do copy
}
```

Comment: To avoid a deadlock, it's best to introduce a livelock? And spin, using 100% CPU?

Answer (score -1):

this is a known problem already there is a std solution.
`std::lock()` can be called on 2 or more mutex at the same time whilst avoiding deadlock's.
[More information here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock)
it does offer a recommendation.

> std::scoped_lock offers a RAII wrapper for this function, and is
>   generally preferred to a naked call to std::lock.

of course this doesn't really allow early releases of one lock above the other so use `std::defer_lock` or `std::adopt_lock` like I did in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713794/1943599) to a similar question.

Answer (score -2):

You can try locking both the mutexes at the same time using scoped_lock or auto_lock.... like bank transfer do...

```
void Transfer(Receiver recv, Sender send)
{
    scoped_lock rlock(recv.mutex);
    scoper_lock slock(send.mutex);

    //do transaction.
}
```

Comment: this  is a recipe for disaster