# Lock on multiple objects

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

How do I acquire lock on multiple items?

Consider the example below,

```
Map<String, Account> accountMap = new HashMap<>(); // key=accountNumber,value=AccountObject

class Account{
     private String accountNumber; // getter & setter
     private double accountBalance; // getter & setter
}
```

I need to transfer funds from one account to another, so I was thinking of having a nested synchronized block and realized that it would lead to deadlock.

```
// bad code
synchronized(accountMap.get(accountNumber1)){
    synchronized(accountMap.get(accountNumber2)){
     // business logic
    }
}
```

Also, I don't want a single lock because it would block the processing of all the threads for one transaction. Something like below

```
//bad code
Object mutex = new Object();

synchronized(mutex){
     // business logic with accountNumber1 & accountNumber2
}
```

How do I go about solving this issue? I need to maintain locks only for two account objects.

Also, possible duplicate(but I wanted to know if there are different solutions). [Preventing deadlock in a mock banking database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076160/preventing-deadlock-in-a-mock-banking-database)

Comment: Use timed lock acquisition, like [Lock.tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to obtain a single lock on multiple objects.  But there are alternatives.

1. You can use a shared (aka "global") lock.  The problem is that this lock could be a bottleneck.
2. You can use some other object as a proxy for the two objects, and obtain a lock on that.  For example, assuming that your accounts have unique ids:

   ```
   String lockName = (acc1.getAccountNumber() + "-" 
                      + acc2.getAccountNumber()).intern();
   synchronized (lockName) {
       // we now have a lock on the combination of acc1 and acc2.
   }
   ```

   (However, this probably doesn't work in your use-case, because it doesn't stop a simultaneous transfer involving one of the two accounts and a third one.)
3. Obtain the locks in a canonical order.   For example.

   ```
   if (acc1.getAccountNumber().compareTo(acc2.getAccountNumber()) < 0) {
       synchronized (acc1) {
           synchronized (acc2) {
               // do transfer
       }
   } else {
       synchronized (acc2) {
           synchronized (acc1) {
               // do transfer
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   If locks are obtained in the same order by all threads, deadlock is not possible.
4. Acquire the locks using `Lock.tryLock` with a times.  However this has a couple of problems:

   - You now need to manage per-account `Lock` objects.
   - There is the (theoretical) problem of "livelock".  To address this you can use randomly generated timeout values.

(Note: don't attempt to use the identity hashcode as a proxy for a unique id.  Identity hashcodes are not unique, and you also have the problem that you could have multiple in-memory `Account` objects that represent the same logical account ... if they are DTOs.)

Comment: there is an argument for using identity hash codes because they are fast to compute. You can use a tie lock for the collision case which is rare.

Comment: Sorry, but which "them" are you referring to?

Comment: oh sorry I was referring to identty hashcodes in my mind :)

Comment: Ah.  I see.  That only deals with one of the problems :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the different solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can lock on two objects and still avoid the deadlock using lock ordering

```
if (accountNumber1 < accountNumber2) {
   synchronized (accountMap.get(accountNumber1)) {
       synchronized (accountMap.get(accountNumber2)) {
           //
       }
   }
} else {
       synchronized (accountMap.get(accountNumber2)) {
           synchronized (accountMap.get(accountNumber1)) {
               //
           }
       }
   }
}
```

This way we avoid the circular wait.

I assume that your Hashmap writes are thread-safe or it is read-only.