# Atomicity of taking multiple locks on x86

Tags: multithreading, c++11, x86

Let's consider multicore CPU x86. Now, we have a some computation that is being executing by 4 threads. To make a computation it is necessary to take two locks (e.g. mutexes). So, it is clear to avoid deadlock we can take them atomically. It means: all mutexes are taken or not.

In C++11 it can be done with `std::lock`.

But, how it can be ensured that it is done atomically? I cannot imagine. I see how to do it on UP systems: just disable interrupts.

Comment: I suppose that it is not atomic. But how it is solved.

Comment: You can see a solution in the boost source code, [reproduced here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814008/multiple-mutex-locking-strategies-and-why-libraries-dont-use-address-comparison)

Comment: `std::lock` doesn't take them atomically with a guarantee.  It can lock and roll back etc.  It just guarantees no deadlocks with other calls to `std::lock`.

Comment: Note that taking all mutexes atomically is not generally a requirement to avoid deadlocks.  Rather, it is sufficient to just make sure any code that wants to hold more than one mutex at a time locks those mutexes in the same order as any other functions that locks those same mutexes do.